# Jupyter lab multiple preferences JSON

Tags: json, jupyter-lab

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The examples I've seen so far only provide for one set of changes not multiple.[image]

Comment: Remove the line 7 and line 19 and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! Tried that and it says "shortcuts is not a valid property"..........

Comment: I guess you are trying to paste into a wrong tab. Shortcuts should go to the shortcuts tab. I do not know which tab you are in because of the cropped screenshot but I guess it's "notebook"

Comment: Oh lord yes, I didn't even realize; kept staring at it for so long. This works. thanks sir!!